# Laravel Eloquent query OR WHERE

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How to write a Laravel Eloquent Query for a Model/table named Country/countries where If I search from any variable and get result according to and the query will search from 3 different column as similar in SQL in given Image.

How to write a similar query in Laravel in Laravel 5.6 /5.7

[image: query and results are in Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `where()` and `orWhere()` functions in Query Builder in laravel

```
$countries = Country::where('name', 'like', '%af%')
    ->orWhere('alpha-2', 'like', '%af%)
    ->orWhere('alpha-3', 'like', '%af%')
    ->get();
```

and if you want to dynamically pass values to `where()` functions.

```
$value = 'af';

$countries = Country::where('name', 'like', "%$value%")
    ->orWhere('alpha-2', 'like', "%$value%")
    ->orWhere('alpha-3', 'like', "%$value%")
    ->get();
```

**Note 'Double Quotation' in variable passing.**

Comment: `'Double Quotation' in variable passing.` Does that make any difference? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: it does, in 'Single Quotation' $variables don't recognize. it takes them as strings.

Answer (score 1):

use your model query like this

```
 Model::where(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('column1', 'like', 'keyword');
        $query->orWhere('column2', 'like', 'keyword');
        $query->orWhere('column3', 'like', 'keyword');
    })->get();
```

Comment: This is more correct, as you can do this combined, without affecting other where clauses like the previous answer